# Consulta entre 4 tablas mysql con claves externas (foreign key)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Tengo estas tablas en mi base de datos para asignar roles a mis usuarios:

```
    tbl usuario
    id
    nombre
    contraseña
    correo
    fk_rol
--------------------
    tbl rol
    id_rol
    nombre
    descripcion
--------------------
    tbl pagina
    id_pagina
    url
---------------------
    tbl rol_pagina
    fk_rol
    fk_pagina
```

Necesito una consulta que me devuelva el nombre de un usuario y las paginas a que tiene acceso, esta es la `query` que tengo de momento, me muestra a que `url` tiene acceso cada `rol`, pero me falta especificar de que usuario

```
select r.nombre, p.Url from rol r, pagina p, rol_pagina n, usuario u 
where r.id_rol = u.fk_rol
and n.fk_rol = r.Id_rol 
and n.fk_pagina = p.id_pagina
and u.fk_rol = 1
```

Tablas:

```
create table Usuario (
   id_usuario int not null auto_increment,
   nombre varchar(30) not null,
   Contrasena varchar(30) not null,
   id_rol int not null,
   primary key (id_usuario),
   constraint fk_rol foreign key (id_rol)
      references rol(id_rol));

create table rol (
   id_rol int not null auto_increment,
   nombre varchar(30) not null,
   primary key (id_rol));

create table pagina (
   id_pagina int not null auto_increment,
   Url varchar(100) not null,
   primary key (id_pagina));

create table rol_pagina (
   id_rol int not null,
   id_pagina int not null,
   constraint fkrol foreign key (id_rol)
      references rol(id_rol),
   constraint fkpagina foreign key (id_pagina)
      references pagina(id_pagina));
```

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir tu definición de creación de tablas ( `CREATE` ) para asegurarse que la respuesta te va funcionar? Ademas sería bueno de ser mas claro que campos de que tablas para que condición quieres en el resultado.

Comment: @StefanNolde ahora lo comparto y muestro algo del query que tengo

Comment: Si ahora podrías agregar las definiciónes de las tablas la pregunta sería más útil para los demás.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para combinar las tablas con sus `FOREIGN KEY`s tienes que usar un JOIN.

El siguiente `SELECT` te da todos usuarios y las paginas a que tienen acceso para el rol con id_rol = 1

```
SELECT r.nombre, p.Url
FROM Usuario AS u INNER JOIN rol AS r ON u.fk_rol = r.id_rol
INNER JOIN rol_pagina AS n ON n.fk_rol = r.id_rol
INNER JOIN pagina AS p ON n.fk_pagina = p.id_pagina
WHERE u.fk_rol = 1 ;
```

Para obtener todas las paginas a cuales un usuario (buscado por id)  tiene acceso, usas:

```
SELECT r.nombre, p.Url
FROM Usuario AS u INNER JOIN rol AS r ON u.fk_rol = r.id_rol
INNER JOIN rol_pagina AS n ON n.fk_rol = r.id_rol
INNER JOIN pagina AS p ON n.fk_pagina = p.id_pagina
WHERE u.id_usuario = ? ;
```

Para buscar las paginas de un usuario identificado por nombre y un rol con id_rol = 1 usas:

```
SELECT r.nombre, p.Url
FROM Usuario AS u INNER JOIN rol AS r ON u.fk_rol = r.id_rol
INNER JOIN rol_pagina AS n ON n.fk_rol = r.id_rol
INNER JOIN pagina AS p ON n.fk_pagina = p.id_pagina
WHERE u.nombre = ? AND u.fk_rol = 1 ;
```

Te recomiendo un tutorial básico de SQL como [este.](http://www.1keydata.com/es/sql/)

Empieza con aprender que significa `SELECT` y para ue se usa `WHERE`.

[Mas información sobre JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: ahi dos from en la consulta...

Comment: ups, perdon, se me olvidó borrar lo que sobraba después de agregar los JOIN. No olvides los `CREATE` por favor.

Comment: la consulta funciona bien.. pero me devuelbe el rol y que paginas tiene ese rol pero de todos, como haria para saber de un solo usuario

Comment: Si quieres trabajar con SQL sería recomendable de aprender SQL. Te voy a solicionar tu problema concreta y dejarte un enlace para estudiar.